# Get Orientation Histogram from Pixel Patch OpenCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I try to get an Orientation Histogram out of the Result of the phase() Method from CV. I try to get the rounded Orientation of each pixel and divide it by 10. So that it would look like that for example for a 5x5 Pixel Patch:

```
{ 1 36 20 3 14
5 16 11 6 9
7 12 34 22 0
34 5 9 21 4
5 21 28 30 1}
```

My Problem is, that I don't really know how to scan each pixel of the Patch and then get the OrientationValue of it to calculate the value for the histogram.

My code for getting the Orientation Mat looks like this:

```
 Mat patch = src(Rect(px,py,15,15));

 Mat Sx;
 Sobel(patch, Sx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);

 Mat Sy;
 Sobel(patch, Sy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);

 Mat mag, ori;
 magnitude(Sx, Sy, mag);
 phase(Sx, Sy, ori, true);

 int** hist;
```

In the variable hist I want to add the values through another method. 
I hope somebody understands what I'm thinking of and can help me.

I have a plan now, how to Iterate through the given Orientation Image I use the loop that is shown in the Documentation [OpenCV Docu](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html)

```
for( i = 0; i < ori.rows; i++){
    for( j = 0; j < ori.cols; j++){
        cout << ori.at<uchar>(i,j) << endl;
    }
}
```

But accessing the Values like that won't give me the Orientation Value. Any Clues?

Comment: ori is from type CV_32F not CV_8U, so try `ori.at<float>(i,j)` or convert Sx with `convertScaleAbs`

Comment: convertScaleAbs wont work because `phase()` needs flaoting point values, so forget about that

Comment: It works thank you! dont know how i could oversee that.

Comment: I got another little Question probably you can help me with that @PSchn If I want to create a OpenCV Histogramm instead of a Int Matrix how can I get this done? I duplicated the example from the OpenCV Docu about Histogramms but It does not work. The Error is: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` like the example abouve I want to seperate it into steps of 10.

Comment: Can you provide your code? And on what operating system are you working?

Comment: Its okay now @PSchn just found the solution. I didnt set the bin and range right but now I got a cv::Mat as histogram and not a int** thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ori` is from type `CV_32F` not `CV_8U`, so try `ori.at<float>(i,j)` ro access the orientation values